# Django admin ManyToMany inline "has no ForeignKey to" error

Tags: django, django-models

I'm setting up the Django admin to the following models:

```py
class Tag(models.Model):                                                 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)                                 

class Quote(models.Model):                                                  
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)                               
    quote = models.CharField(max_length=1000)                               
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

With the following code:

```
class TagInline(admin.TabularInline):                                                                                               
    model = Tag                                                             
                                                                            
class QuoteAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                                         
    list_display = ('author', 'quote')                                      
    inlines = (TagInline,)                                                  
                                                                            
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                                           
    pass                                                                    
                                                                            
admin.site.register(Quote, QuoteAdmin)                                      
admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
```

When trying to view the admin page to add a `Quote`, the page shows an error saying `<class 'quotes.models.Tag'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'quotes.models.Quote'>`. This didn't happen before I added an inline. What's the problem? How do I correctly add a `Tag` as an inline?

*(I spent a good 20 minutes searching for an answer; I found similar questions but none of their answers worked for me.)*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345673/django-no-foreignkey-but-its-a-manytomanyfield

Answer (score 222, accepted):

[Admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models) has a section dedicated to inlining with many-to-many relationships. You should use `Quote.tags.through` as a model for `TagInline`, instead of `Tag` itself.

Comment: If I have a modal which has many `manytomany field`, that means for each one it needs a `Inline` and they are different?

Comment: @Rmatt For reversed many-to-many relations

`model = Tag.quote_set.related.through`

Comment: Is there a trick for making the through model appear as a raw id field instead of listing very possible row in the DB?

Comment: and this is why I start to love Django

Comment: How to use filter_horizontal in that case? .through has no the model fields. So I get attribute error :(

Comment: @mlissner if you use the model name instead column name should work. For instance, my auto generated "through table" had a field "customuser_id", then I used `raw_id_fields = ("customuser",)`

Comment: 11 years on and you just saved me! Thanks! This was easy to miss in the documentation.

Comment: This answer is still valid in 2024. Thank you for your response.