# Django Admin Inlines and AbstractUser

Tags: python, django

I'm having issues with trying to have MtoM in my admin.py.
I keep getting an error that says:
`<class 'demo.admin.CustomUserAdmin'>: (admin.E013) The value of 'fieldsets[2][1]["fields"]' cannot include the ManyToManyField 'groups', because that field manually specifies a relationship
 model.`

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from app.forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from app.models import User, GroupUser, RoleAssign

class GroupUserInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = GroupUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = User
    inlines = [ GroupUserInline, ]

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

and these are my models:

```
#models.py
class Group(models.Model):
    name  = models.CharField(max_length=240)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, through='RoleAssign')

class User(AbstractUser):
    username   = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    password   = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False)
    email      = models.EmailField(max_length=256, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    S3         = models.TextField()
    groups     = models.ManyToManyField(Group, through='GroupUser')

class GroupUser(models.Model):
    user  = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

Does anyone have any details why my inline may not be working? Or should I be trying a different method?

Comment: I've the same problem? How did you solve it?

Comment: @FabrizioA I never found a solution to this. My only "work around" was to create my own `admin.py` and not follow standard Django methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try use `model = User.groups.through` in `GroupUserInline` class

View more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479999/django-admin-manytomany-inline-has-no-foreignkey-to-error), I think this can help you.